# Restriction on retrieving file information from a folder

Tags: onedrive

I am trying to get information about files in a folder using https://apis.live.net/v5.0/folderid/files?

This particular folder of mine has around 5200 files. So I am getting a readtimeout when I make the above mentioned request. Is there any restriction on the number of files that I can make the request.

Note : I am able to successfully retrieve the file information from folder if I restrict the file count to 500 say  https://apis.live.net/v5.0/folderid/files?limit=500

Answer (score 0):

In general it's good to page queries that could potentially return a large number of requests. You could try using the `limit` query parameter in combination with the `offset` query parameter to read sets of the children at a time and see if that works better for you.

I'll quote in the relevant information from the documentation for ease of reference:

> Specify the first item to get by setting the offset parameter in the preceding code to the index of the first item that you want to get. For example, to get two items starting with the third item, use FOLDER_ID/files?limit=2&offset=3.
>   Note  In the JavaScript Object Notation (JSON)-formatted object that's returned, you can look in the paging object for the previous and next structures, if they apply, to get the offset and limit parameter values of the previous and next entries, if they exist.

You may also want to consider swapping to the [new API](https://dev.onedrive.com), which has it's own paging model (using the `next` links).